# App for synchronizing only folders

Tags: windows, sync, portable-apps

This is the exact situation I'm in. I have amassed over the years quite a lot of portable apps for the Windows OS. I also decide to add or remove portable apps as time goes on. I have at least 3 computers in which I'd like to have those apps synchronized. I'm currently using AllwaySync to do that.

Problem: When running apps, they often generate small .log, .xml, .ini files which are relevant for that particular machine. Every time I sync, it would ask me if I want to sync those files or not which is kinda annoying.

Imagined solution: If I have a sync app that only checks for folders, this should kinda solve my problem. I mean the program would only check if there is a folder named e.g. FirefoxPortable in both machines and if this is true, it would move one even if the file content of FirefoxPortable in each machine is completely different.

Is there a program that does that?

Also, from my description, would you suggest a different solution completely that is better?

Comment: I don't know about AllwaySync specifically, but most comparison programs I have worked with will allow you to ignore specific files/folder or files/folders that match a given pattern.  Is that not supported in AllwaySync?  It just means you need to set up some rules.

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic on Superuser